# We need a place (that/where) we can stay for a few days

Tags: sentence-structure, relative-clauses

> We need a place (*that/where*) we can stay for a few days.

Might I trouble you to tell me whether 'that' is also possible in the question? I think 'where' alone is correct because 'stay' is an intransitive verb. 'Where' can be paraphrased into 'in which', but 'that' is just 'that'.

We need a place *in which* we can stay for a few days. (O)

We need a place *that* we can stay for a few days. (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb "stay" is not normally transitive:

> I stayed at the hotel  (Okay)
>   I stayed the hotel  (very odd)

Similarly you should not say

> A place that I can stay  (odd)

This would make "stay" a transitive verb.

Instead, you use "where", or "in which".  (Don't worry too much about restrictive and non-restrictive clauses, or if you do worry about it, you should know it is about intonation, not word choice)